# protractor get url after click()

Tags: angularjs, protractor

i'm new with protractor.. i need you'r help..
my code go like this..

```
describe('Protractor Demo Charts', function () {
           var url = 'https://angularjs.org/';


it('should get the value of attribute d', function () {
    browser.get(url);
    element(by.css('.btn-warning')).click().then(function(text){

        expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toContain('0BxgtL8yFJbacQmpCc1NMV3d5dnM');
        }

    );

});
```

});

my problem is that browser.getCurrentUrl() still return me the base url (the page that i came from 'https://angularjs.org/' )

how can i get the new Url (the URL **AFTER** the click )?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May you should wait until the page has been loaded.
Try this way :

```
describe('Protractor Demo Charts', function () {
     var url = 'https://angularjs.org/';

     it('should get the value of attribute d', function () {
         browser.get(url);
         browser.sleep(2000);
         $('.btn-warning').click();
         expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toContain('0BxgtL8yFJbacQmpCc1NMV3d5dnM');
     });
});
```

From the [doc](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/browser-setup):

Protractor will ensure that commands will automatically run in sync. For example, in the following code, element(by.model(...)).click() will run before browser2.$('.css').click():

```
browser.get('http://www.angularjs.org');
browser2.get('http://localhost:1234');

browser.sleep(5000);
element(by.model(...)).click();
browser2.$('.css').click();
```